# How do i return a block of code in ruby

Tags: ruby, return, block

I want to return a multi-line block of code from one function to be executed by another function

for example

```
def foo 
  return #block
end

def bar(&block)
  block.call
end

bar(foo)
```

Does any one know how to do this?
Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: What are you trying to do? There is probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a Proc. There are several methods that create them — primarily `proc`, `lambda` and `->`. You just pass a block to one of these functions and it will wrap the block in a Proc object. (There are subtle differences in how the three methods handle arguments, but you usually don't need to care.) So you could write:

```
def foo 
  proc { puts "Look ma, I got called!" }
  # you don't need the return keyword in Ruby -- the last expression reached returns automatically
end

def bar(&block)
  block.call
end

bar(&foo) # You need the & operator to convert the Proc back into a block
```

Answer (score 2):

You can return a `Proc` object:

```
def foo
    return Proc.new { ... }
end

def bar(block)
    block.call
end

bar(foo)
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/1fh9Yr)'s the live example.

Comment: It would be more natural to have the method take a block and convert to and from a Proc as needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
def foo 
  Proc.new {
    # code here
  } 
end
```

No need to use return, it is implicit.

Comment: @Jefffrey - Not in ruby. I found that some developers overuse `return` statement and they miss that some method returns what they wouldn't expect (especially popular mistake in before_save hooks)

Comment: In my opinion, return should almost only be used in the first line or two in the method when you are checking the parameters or if nothing needs to be done. If I see a explicit return when it's not needed it confuses me (and most experienced Ruby programmers I think)